# What are some good tutorials on using jQuery and/or HTML to build games?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm not new to JQuery, but I've done a limited amount of AJAX calls before. I'm looking to sharpen my abilities in this department (by a lot), so any suggestions/links that you deem appropriate would be much appreciated. Wading through Google just doesn't seem to yield any applicable results for me. They're either seemingly outdated, not really on subject, or what I already understand how to do (think extremely simple).

I'm also looking into building small games not built in Flash. Either JQuery/AJAX or HTML5 (which I freely admit I don't know much about at this point) could work here since I'm interested in learning either to that extent, so Pros/Cons as to which language would be preferable would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Ideally, the best method for learning for me has always to develop some project with practical value, i.e. does something to make my life easier, and then learn the separate pieces of code required to make it actually work. Practical application trumps tutorials every day IMHO.

Comment: Your question looks like two questions: one asking for AJAX tutorials, and one asking about building games.

Comment: I agree, especially since I'm an extremely hands-on type, but as I told sje397, I think maybe I've just hit a "wall". I'm mainly asking for suggestions as to where I could go for good examples to look through? Maybe a place that I could test my code against. Sorry I can't be more specific. It's kind of hard to ask a community where to turn when I can't really spell out what I'm looking for, I guess. However I think as far as HTML5 goes, sje397 gave me a pretty good link. @Paul: I was mainly asking if a combo of JQuery/AJAX was better than HTML5 for building games. It seemed relevant.

Comment: @foxtrot, for a Flash-less web-based game, you'll probably need some combination of presentation (html, and maybe some of the newer technologies introduced in html5) and scripting (javascript/jQuery).  The two are definitely not mutually exclusive, in fact they sort of depend on each other.

Comment: Additionally, a list of tutorials that you've already read (or concepts that you already understand) would be very helpful as far as suggesting additional tutorials and resources.  For example, have you already read the jQuery Ajax documentation? http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @foxtrot: ah, yes, I see what you were asking now. The HTML5 spec specifies features of both HTML and JavaScript, so it’s not really an alternative to JavaScript. And AJAX is just a small feature of JavaScript: specifially, it’s the `XMLHTTPRequest` object, the thing that allows you to make HTTP requests, and get their results, via JavaScript.

Comment: @mlms13: Yes, and that was actually the most helpful one. @Paul: That is what I was asking about, though I guess I should have said "pure JQuery/AJAX or based around HTML5" - what I'm looking for as far as this is concerned is not to alienate my users. I'm not sure of the compatibility (I have heard of issues) and don't want to include code that would do so.

Answer (score 1):

I have saved several good links to articles on both AJAX, jQuery, and JSON on my delicious account:
http://www.delicious.com/Woody/jquery+ajax

This one was definitely worth taking a look (can only post one link):
5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery | Nettuts+

Comment: That is a pretty rockin' collection of resources.  I'm going to favorite this question just so I don't forget about that list.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll be checking them out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this site to be the best resource for learning jQuery & Ajax. It's easy to bring up a whole bunch of jQuery/ajax stuff by searching, and just by browsing through the questions and answers, and reading anything that sounds like it might be something you want to know about, you can learn *heaps* in a very short time. And, of couse, [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) are always entertaining :)

Not so sure about using SO to learn HTML5 though. This site is good: http://html5doctor.com/ ... I just have their posts come up in my news reader.

Comment: I think my problem with using SO to bring up the information I want is mainly that I'm not really sure what to ask at this point. I've used AJAX to, say, submit a form and return results to the same page before, but not in a way that's really acceptable to me. I feel like I could do better, code it simpler, I guess. I will look into that site for html5 though - thanks. :)

Comment: @foxtrot: I'm not talking about asking questions - just go to the questions list and look around. You can generally find a couple of jQuery questions on the 'recent' tab every time you look, and then you can decide if it's something you know already or not.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out - though most of those questions I can answer already.

Answer (score 0):

1. AJAX isn’t a language, it‘s a small feature of JavaScript. You don’t build things “in” AJAX, you build parts of their functionality *using* AJAX.
2. There’s a lot of stuff in HTML5, but the main bit likely to be relevant to building games is [the `<canvas>` tag](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html). This tag gives you a fixed drawing area, onto which you draw things using JavaScript.

In short, you need to learn JavaScript. And for that, you can’t get much better than [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805531). Might be worth waiting until the new edition next February.

Comment: I know that AJAX isn't a language. I never said nor meant to imply that it was (if I did). But I'm not going to argue schematics here. That's ridiculous. However, thank you for #2.

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding — it was just when you typed jQuery/AJAX, I figured you were describing them as alternatives. Also, whilst I’m in pedant mode, I think you mean “semantics”, not “schematics”.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [the `$.ajax` API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Look at the examples, read the comments.

If you can sit down and read the source http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.ajax
It's useful to have an appreciation of what it does under the hood. Admittedly trying to read the source might actaully scare you more then do you good.

Next you find yourself some kind of backend and play around with ajax a bit then set up a small project to really get some experience.

Remember, that AJAX is simple a means to communicate between server and client, an alternative for that would also be the HTML5 websockets or simple form submission.

In terms of writing games the HTML5 you use would mainly be canvas and audio. Ajax is only applicable if the game interacts with the server (i.e. is multiplayer).

Alternatively to HTML5 canvas use you can write a browser game entirely using raw JS (or a framework of choice like jQuery) and the DOM.

Comment: I have read the API, and it wouldn't scare me at all, so thank you for that. I have a backend, and actually do have working AJAX. Perhaps what I'm looking for is more around how JQuery and AJAX could communicate and work better together than the actual AJAX part. :) Also, while I'm thinking about it, do you have any suggestions as to how, if I did use HTML5, working simple things like say, high score, would be possible without AJAX? I admit I'm entirely new to building games and am quite fascinated with it.

Comment: I recently started building games using HTML5 and I didnt really find any tutorials myself. So I just started writing adhoc. I used websockets (which are TCP) for server-client communication. Just to say it again you only need AJAX to communicate with the server. There are plenty of singleplayer client based games you can write that do not use ajax. One thing I aught to mention is that I'm only supporting chrome due to the technological limitations of most browsers.

Comment: Well, I assume keeping a user's high score (or five) would require communication with the server, as well as any 'badges', 'achievements', etc, that they might acquire along the way. Also, your last sentence is the main reason why I'm shying away from using HTML5. I myself use Firefox, other members of my site use various other browsers, including IE. Limiting them on the browser they could use limits me, since not all of them will be technology-capable per se.

Comment: @foxtrot it completely depends on what you want to do. I want to create a realtime multiplayer game with twitch reaction. Only chrome will support the technology to make it _playable_ . I guess what your asking is using ajax to make a save & load function :) ajax should be fine for that.

Comment: More like simple sends to the server for high scores, etc. Although it would be pretty awesome to make a multiplayer game, I've got to start somewhere. The kinds of games I'm looking to make right now (mainly so I can learn what I need to), are extremely simple things. Sudoku, cards, etc. But I'd like for them to have high score tables, keep track of each user's personal best, that sort of thing. Later on I'd like to have achievements in some of my games, so knowing how to create "points" (I guess?) would also be great.

Comment: @foxtrot where you want to go from here is dependant on the backend in terms of examples. Writing generic ajax calls for any backend is a bit complex and its far simpler to tell us what server technology you want to use and redirect to relevant examples.

Comment: PHP5/mySQL4. AJAX calls are not really a problem per gaming conversation as creating the actual games are, I believe. I can provide any information based on that. I'd prefer to use HTML5 in conjunction but as it stands I don't believe I can, since forcing my users to stick to a particular browser would be out of the question and I haven't been given any indication that wouldn't happen so far. I hear a lot about "IE not compatible" and, while I don't condone IE at all, I know some of my users do use it.

Comment: @foxtrot in terms of HTML5, the `<canvas>` which is your rendering screen is reasonable cross browser and can be emulated sufficiently in IE. IE9 is around the corner and will support some of the technology. I believe you'll have a harder time emulating audio & websockets. Although as long as your not having to support IE6/7 all the technology is there its just simply a _pain_ to develop.

Comment: Actaully let me stress that. All of the HTML5 technology can be emulated to work cross browser. It's just simple a _pain_ to write an efficient & fun (and significantly complex. Simple games are fine.) cross browser game like that.

Comment: For now, there won't be audio, and probably only by request later on. So we'll assume it will always be visuals-only. However of course I want those visuals to look good, even on the simpler games. :) I am of the opinion however that one should try to cater to as many browsers as possible (excluding IE6 because, well, come on it's IE6) and put the least amount of effort on the user as possible. From a business perspective, some will leave if your website doesn't work with what they have, you know? All this said, do you have any in-depth guides for the canvas tag and/or HTML5 game tutorials?

Comment: Searching for them with my apparently less-than-amazing Google powers seems to bring a lot of "here play this HTML5 game!" and not so much "here's how to properly assemble a basic game using HTML5/JS/etc"

Comment: @foxtrot you forgot the old trick of preprending any google query with "mdc " https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas the mdc developer  database is vast, detailed and high quality. You will find everything you need here. Be wary that canvas is quite a low level API. IE will deal with visuals fine, but IE is _slow_. There is no way around that. You will need to make your game efficient so that it runs smoothly in IE. This limits your options

Comment: Thank you for that. I was under the impression that IE is slow no matter what it did. Haha. I plan on making sure that my users are aware I'd rather them use a different browser than IE, for sure, but as far as actually accessing it, I'd rather it be available, even if it is less than desirable. Maybe if they see it it'll convince them to switch. We can all hope. Also, while I'm at it, that's the main reason that I asked the question to begin with. I'm attempting to better myself as far as my actual jQuery/AJAX code and flow are concerned. I try to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @foxtrot for the record my personal preference would be to avoid relying too heavily on jQuery in the clientside. For some of jQuery's utilities I would rely on something like http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/ instead and of course you can use $.ajax :). At some point I would recommend you do some XHR directly without any wrappers to get a feeling for how it works cross browser. Personally I don't have any need for jQuery on my client due to relying on the websocket API for server-client communication

Comment: Thank you again Raynos. I'll look into that, and the websocket API.

Comment: @foxtrot Currently the websocket API is considered "unsecure". This has caused FF4 & opera to drop support for it. Websockets only work natively in chrome. You can use socket.IO (You may be stuck to a node.js backend, but hey node.js is awesome) to emulate websockets, Alternatively you can create your own flash bridge to emulate websockets. Websockets are _far_ from cross browser compliant. You only need websockets if you want realtime two way connection between client & server.

Comment: Also be wary of "cheating". It's very easy for someone to read your source and use your ajax method to send fake highscores to your server. This is a completely different subject to deal with.

Comment: Hm. They'll be interesting to look into in case I want to include a game of that nature in the future (probably). As far as cheating is concerned, I have thought about that and have been trying to come up with a backend solution ... none so far but it's rolling around in there.